# Passing parameters to maven plugin while writing unit tests

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mojo

I have a maven mojo plugin with parameters like this:

```
public class SomeMojoPlugin
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    @Parameter( property = "templatefile", required = true )
    private File templateFile;
```

And I want to write unit tests for this plugin.
How to pass this property/parameter "templatefile" in test methods?

Comment: this sounds like an integration test to me.. you are trying to use resouces outside of the class under test

Comment: Simple solution will be expose setter for the fields and set the values to them. If you don't want to change the existing class under test, you can use reflection to set those values

Comment: What are you using to launch those tests? This is too broad to answer. The [plugin testing harness](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/) can do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven documentation has a page about [How To Use Maven Plugin Testing Harness](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html).

Basically extending AbstractMojoTestCase, implementing the methods for the lifecycle and providing a sample pom.xml file for the test.

```
public class MyMojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Parameter usually marks a class field. If it is protected or private and you want to get access to it, you can add a Setter like:

```
public void setTemplateFile(File templateFile) {
    this.templateFile = templateFile;
}
```

If you use IntellijIDEA, just press Alt+Ins to create it easier...